# How to kill a AsyncTack thread properly in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I subclass an AsyncTask in my Android project.

I want to implement a feature that allow user to cancel the current AsyncTack and start a new one if the current task take too much time.

```
MyAsyncTask mat = new MyAsyncTask();
```

When the user click the cancel button, I will implement the following code and then start a new task.

```
mat.cancel(true);
```

However, I realize later that the new task doesn't start until the old task is finish. The old task tread is still executing.

I check the official document on google. It seems that I should call  the following statement in ***doInBackGroud(Params... params)***.

```
if (isCancelled()) break;
```

The problem is I found that the code below is responsible for taking long time.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

But how can I check whether the task is cancelled or not while ***httpClient.execute(httpPost)*** is executing?
Is there some method like ***onProgressChanged(int progress)*** that I can override in DefaultHttpClient?

Comment: set connection time out in your networkcall.

Comment: you can call `httpPost.abort();` to abort  current http request after or before AsyncTask is Cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to implement a feature that allow user to cancel the current
>   AsyncTack and start a new one if the current task take too much time.

Since you cannot start a new task until the old task is finish, you can create a new instance of the Asyntask. In fact, its a bad idea to use a instance of AsyncTask multiple times.
After your

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

You can check if it was canceled

```
if(!isCanceled()){

}
```

Look in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), last line under Threading Rules.
**Update** 
as comment pointed out. Depends on your platform , so check the platform version before execute.

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
    else {
      myTask.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that, depending on the platform version, by default different AsyncTasks still use the same thread. That means that a new AsyncTask would still be blocked until the first one finishes, unless you explicitly call it using an executor that holds several threads.

Comment: But what I really want to know is that, what if the user tap cancel button while httpClient.execute(httpPost) is executing. cause that statement could take really long time.

Comment: if the user tap cancel. httpClient.execute(httpPost) will still be running on your first instance. You can then fire another instance to retry. Or as other answers pointed out. Have your httpClient execute `httpPost.abort();` before your fire the new instance. But remeber to cancel(); your first one after you abort.

Comment: @Dragonwarrior : when User press cancel button then first call `httpPost.abort();` to abort current http request then after `2-3sec` call `mat.cancel(true);` to cancel Asyntask

Answer (score 1):

You need to abort your request by calling `abort` on your `httpPost` object. This will cause the `execute` method to return immediately and to stop blocking your thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually avoid using AsyncTask altogether. AsyncTasks are prone to memory leaks and are poorly tied to the Activity lifecycle so you'll end up getting yourself into trouble.

Consider using [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/blob/master/README.md) as not only it will help you solve your question, but it'll avoid the problems with AsyncTasks and skip having to write stuff manually with HttpClient. I am not one of the devs for RoboSpice, but I've started using it recently and it's an excellent project.